# No me pinta los datos en tabla HTML desde AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html

Chic@s, buenas!! Les comento el problema que estoy teniendo:

Estoy haciendo una web muy basica que se comunica con una BBDD y puedo leer los datos, o añadirle nuevos. El tema es que no me esta trayendo los datos desde AJAX y no entiendo por que.

Esta seria la web:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En rojo remarque la zona donde deberían aparecer datos. Y como verán en la parte de RED de las herramientas del desarrollador del navegador, me aparecen los datos

Y este es el código:
Archivo **traker_list.php**:

```
<?php

include('conexion_bbdd.php');

$query = "SELECT id, id_obra, tracker, id_estado, kks FROM public.lucio_prueba";
$rs = $db->Execute($query);
$row=$rs->fields;

// if( !rs ) {
//     die('Query failed.');
// }

$json = array();
foreach ($rs as $row) {
    $json[] = array(
        'id' => $row["id"],
        'id_obra' => $row["id_obra"],
        'tracker' => $row["tracker"],
        'id_estado' => $row["id_estado"],
        'kks' => $row["kks"]
    );
}
$jsonstring = json_encode($json);

echo $jsonstring;
```

?>
Archivo **app.js**:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'tracker_list.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
            //console.log(response);
            let trackers = JSON.parse(response);    // Convierto el string en un json
            let template = '';                      // Creo una plantilla
            
            // Recorro los trackers
            trackers.forEach(tracker => {
                template += `
                    <tr> 
                        <th>${tracker.id}</th>
                        <th>${tracker.id_obra}</th>
                        <th>${tracker.tracker}</th>
                        <th>${tracker.id_estado}</th>
                        <th>${tracker.kks}</th>
                    </tr>
                `
            });
            // Selecciona el elemento trackers y lo llena con la plantilla template
            $('#trackers').html(template);
        }
    });
```

Archivo **index.html**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cloudmify</title>
    <link href="../Lucio/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand ml-2">Tracker</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control mr-sm-2"  placeholder="Buscar Tracker">
                <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
            </form> <!--.Search form-->
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container p-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form id="tracker-form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Tracker name" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" id="kks" class="form-control" placeholder="Tracker KKS">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" min="1" id="id_obra" class="form-control" placeholder="Obra ID">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" min="1" max="13" id="id_estado" class="form-control" placeholder="Estado ID">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center">
                                Guardar
                            </button>
                        </form> <!--.form-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="card my-4" id="tracker-result">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul id="container"></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Id_obra</th>
                            <th>Tracker</th>
                            <th>Id_estado</th>
                            <th>KKS</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody class="trackers"></tbody>
                </table> <!--.table-->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="lib/Jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Agradezco infinitamente la ayuda de alguien de la comunidad y por favor perdonen si tengo errores al realizar la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error esta en que estas usando un `id` para llenar con los datos pero en tu elemento lo tienes como `clase` cambia esto: `<tbody class="trackers"></tbody>`
por esto : `<tbody id="trackers"></tbody>`.
Así vas a poder agregar el contenido por su id, como ya lo vienes haciendo `$('#trackers').html(template);`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! Error de novato!! Abrazo

Comment: Si te sirvió mi respuesta, acéptala por favor como respuesta correcta, te lo agradecería saludos.

Comment: Listo!! Perdona no sabia eso!